# xbacklight not working

Tags: debian, display, backlight

I have my ASUS X556U with DualBoot between W10 and Debian Jessie, but I need to regulate the brightness.

I've been serching in Google and I found xbacklight, but I have a problem while executing it:

```
barreeeiroo@Debian-Diego ~> xbacklight -dec 10
No outputs have backlight property
barreeeiroo@Debian-Diego ~>
```

---

Then I search in Google more info about the problem, and I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/715306/xbacklight-no-outputs-have-backlight-property-no-sys-class-backlight-folder), but it causes another problem:

```
barreeeiroo@Debian-Diego ~> 
sudo ln -s /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/rtsx_usb_sdmmc.4/leds/mmc0::/brightness  /sys/class/backlight
[sudo] password for barreeeiroo: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/sys/class/backlight/brightness’: Operation not permitted
barreeeiroo@Debian-Diego ~>
```

I've adapted the route to my computer

Then I tried to use `chmod` and `chown`, but is the same problem.

---

So, my questions are:

1. Is possible to fix that error?
2. Is there any other method to manage brightness in Debian?

*Thanks*

Comment: If you have "Operation not permitted" on `chmod` or `chown` make sure to run the commands as root (using e.g. `sudo`)

Comment: The same @Anthon, not working

Comment: I believe `xrandr` also has a backlight brightness setting - I think that uses a different mechanism to accomplish it, so maybe you'll have more luck that way? (note that there's a backlight brightness and 'artificial' brightness setting - make sure you have the right one)

Comment: So, how to use xrandr in my laptop? @Wyatt8740

Comment: I've not got a linux box in front of me that uses xrandr, but something like `xrandr --output LVDS1 --{backlight command goes here, check 'man xrandr'} {number}`. LVDS1 is the primary lcd on intel drivers but may be different on other graphics chipsets. check `xrandr` output without args for a list of devices.

Comment: That output coudn't be found @Wyatt8740

Comment: in that case as I said run xrandr without args to list outputs.

Comment: Okey, I will search about xrandr @Wyatt8740

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/739654/xbacklight-is-not-working-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Answer (score 14):

Arch Linux has the following to say about [xbacklight](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#xbacklight):

> Brightness can be set using the xorg-xbacklight package.
>
> Note: xbacklight only works with intel. Radeon does not support the
>   RandR backlight property. xbacklight currently does not work with the
>   modesetting driver.
>
> To set brightness to 50% of maximum:
>
> ```
> $ xbacklight -set 50
> ```
>
> Increments can be used instead of absolute values, for example to
>   increase or decrease brightness by 10%:
>
> ```
> $ xbacklight -inc 10
> $ xbacklight -dec 10
> ```
>
> If you get the "No outputs have backlight property" error, it is
>   because xrandr/xbacklight does not choose the right directory in
>   `/sys/class/backlight`. You can specify the directory by setting the
>   Backlight option of the device section in `xorg.conf`. For instance, if
>   the name of the directory is `intel_backlight`, the device section can
>   be configured as follows:
>
> ```
> /etc/X11/xorg.conf
> -------------------
> Section "Device"
>     Identifier  "Card0"
>     Driver      "intel"
>     Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
> EndSection
> ```

The following worked for me on Debian Stretch LXDE.

1. Checked the backlight directory: `ls /sys/class/backlight`.  I happen to have `intel_backlight`.
2. To get the Identifier, I ran `xrandr --verbose`.  Mine happened to be `0x72`.
3. Checking `/etc/X11/`, I found no `xorg.conf`, so I made my own and entered the information I had found:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier  "0x72"
       Driver      "intel"
       Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
   EndSection
   ```
4. I then rebooted.  It worked from there.
5. Since LXDE runs openbox, I edited `~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml` and inserted the following keybindings:

   ```
   <!-- Increase backlight 10% -->
   <keybind key="XF86MonBrightnessUp">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>xbacklight -inc 10</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>

   <!-- Decrease backlight 10% -->
   <keybind key="XF86MonBrightnessDown">
     <action name="Execute">
       <command>xbacklight -dec 10</command>
     </action>
   </keybind>
   ```

Comment: For me the best solution since xrandr could not increase the brightness.

Comment: This worked for me even though I wasn't getting any error. 
Intel HD Graphics 4000, Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 6):

Just managed to control my screen brightness in Debian with xrandr.

`xrandr --output [your display] --brightness 0.8`

You can find your display name by typing `xrandr` - you'll see it as something like "[your display] connected primary 1920x1080..."

Next up... key bindings!

Comment: According to `man xrandr`: *“--brightness brightness […] However, this is a software only modification, if your hardware has support to actually change the  brightness,  you  will  probably prefer to use xbacklight.”*

Comment: This seems to change the color temperature too, or maybe it's cause I have Gnome Night Light on.

Comment: this answer is incorrect, because this does *not* change the backlight, only the software brightness, which is something else

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this literally for years, this finally worked

Answer (score 5):

There is a direct `xbacklight` replacement that is compatible with non-Intel drivers: [`acpilight`](https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight). Arch Linux already has it [packaged](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=acpilight), on Debian you will need to install it manually:

```
git clone https://gitlab.com/wavexx/acpilight
cd acpilight
sudo make install
```

`acpilight` replaces the `xbacklight` command, supporting most of its syntax and adding a few extra features like keyboard backlight control on compatible hardware. The brightness is set via sysfs rather than `xrandr` extensions, so it's wise to check if `/sys/class/backlight/` is populated before trying to use it.

Comment: excellent. This helped a lot.

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

One potential cause of error may also be the modesetting display driver. `xbacklight` does [currently not work with modesetting](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/issues/47).

Another option: Using [brightnessctl](https://github.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl), which uses udev and systemd to take care of the whole permission stuff.

On Ubuntu 18.04, the udev rule wasn't installed properly, so I had to get it manually:

```
cd /etc/udev/rules.d
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hummer12007/brightnessctl/master/90-brightnessctl.rules
```

and then add myself to the necessary groups:

```
usermod -a -G video input <user>
```

After rebooting, I could use `brightnessctl s 10%+` and created a keybinding for that in i3.